# How to change column field from the table by using joins in MS ACCESS?

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, set

Ok, I had very long research about this problem, and can't get the answer, so I hope you can help :)

The problem:

When I use this sql query in Access:

```
SELECT PARTNERI.SIFRA, Sum(FAKTURE.ZA_UPLATU)-Sum(UPLATEF.IZNOS) + SUM(PARTNERI.DUGUJE)
FROM ((UPLATEF RIGHT JOIN PARTNERI ON UPLATEF.SIFRA = PARTNERI.SIFRA) LEFT JOIN FAKTURE ON PARTNERI.SIFRA = FAKTURE.S_KUP)
GROUP BY PARTNERI.SIFRA;
```

I get a resultset and it's fine, but...
I want to update column from PARTNERI table, and I wrote this:

```
UPDATE PARTNERI SET NG_DUGUJE_DOB = 
SELECT Sum(FAKTURE.ZA_UPLATU)-Sum(UPLATEF.IZNOS) + SUM(PARTNERI.DUGUJE)
FROM ((UPLATEF RIGHT JOIN PARTNERI ON UPLATEF.SIFRA = PARTNERI.SIFRA) LEFT JOIN FAKTURE ON PARTNERI.SIFRA = FAKTURE.S_KUP)
```

;

And I get a syntax error...I don't know what to do... If you know the answer please let me know... P.S. I'm beginner of using SQL... Thanks :)

Edit:

Ok, I tried something and wrote this:

```
   UPDATE PARTNERI SET PARTNERI.NG_DUGUJE_DOB = 
(SELECT Sum(FAKTURE.ZA_UPLATU)-Sum(UPLATEF.IZNOS) + SUM(PARTNERI.DUGUJE)
FROM ((UPLATEF RIGHT JOIN PARTNERI ON UPLATEF.SIFRA = PARTNERI.SIFRA) LEFT JOIN FAKTURE ON PARTNERI.SIFRA = FAKTURE.S_KUP))
```

...this time I got this error:

> Operation must use updateable query.

EDIT:

I have managed to solve the problem using DSum function that you guys told me and it works great!

Thank you very much for your answers, I'm very grateful for your help! :)

Comment: How many rows does the first query select?

Comment: The first query selects 360 rows, and that's all rows from PARTNERI table...

Comment: I think you missing a where clause, your selecting the info to update, but the first table doesn't know how to match up the updates, is there an Id field you can use? That's my best guess anyway

Comment: Think about it. You are trying to a update a single field with 380 rows. I think you need to define just what is you want to do before we can help you.

Comment: I want to edit column NG_DUGUJE_DOB from PARTNERI table with values that my first select query returned... I want that resultset that I get with the first select query to use to update that column...I hope I was clear...

Answer (score 1):

This is a known limitation of the Access Database Engine: daft as it may sound, it cannot `UPDATE` using a query involving an summarization (aggregate), even when using its own proprietary syntax, and there is no 'pure SQL' workaround:

[Microsoft Help and Support: Update Query Based on Totals Query Fails](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/116142)

I'm on record as saying that Access's `UPDATE` syntax is its worst failure.

Comment: +1 Hunted high and low for a KB article that describes that problem

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it like this :

```
UPDATE  (PARTNERI LEFT JOIN UPLATEF ON UPLATEF.SIFRA = PARTNERI.SIFRA) LEFT JOIN FAKTURE ON PARTNERI.SIFRA = FAKTURE.S_KUP SET PARTNERI.NG_DUGUJE_DOB = Sum(FAKTURE.ZA_UPLATU)-Sum(UPLATEF.IZNOS) + SUM(PARTNERI.DUGUJE)
```

Comment: Well, I copied your code and it says that ')' is missing, so I added it at the end of the query, and I still get that syntax error... :/

Comment: I've got this error: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 
'UPLATEF.SIFRA = PARTNERI.SIFRA LEFT JOIN FAKTURE ON PARTNERI.SIFRA = FAKTURE.S_KUP'

Comment: Maybe it needs parenthesis for the first join . give it a try again

Comment: Hmmm, I tried something and edited my post and got this error: "Operation must use updateable query.". Not sure what I'm missing this time :/

Comment: Hmmm, I'm really confused know,maybe because it's too late here, I might go to bed and sleep now and try tomorrow to find an answer if I can xD

Comment: @VladimirSavić `Operation must use an updateable query` is a bug in Access. You can use [`DSum`](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/domain/dsum.php) to work around this and achieve the required result. Similar to `UPDATE Table SET Column = DSum("A-B-C", "OtherTable", "OtherTable.Column = " & CStr(JoinColumn))`